# Javascript function efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running a program that has a lot of modal popups that the user navigates and closes 1 or 2 at a time. Generally, is it better in javascript to close the specific ones in each function? Or should I create a function that closes everything at once, even ones that aren't open?

Example:

```
//when only 1 & 2 are open
$('#btnA').click(function () {
    modal1.style.display = "none"; 
    modal2.style.display = "none";
    //unique code
 }
//when 1, 3 & 4 are open
$('#btnB').click(function () {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
    modal3.style.display = "none"; 
    modal4.style.display = "none";
    //unique code
 }
//when only 5 & 6 are open
$('#btnC').click(function () {
    modal5.style.display = "none"; 
    modal6.style.display = "none";
    //unique code
 }
```

Compared to:

```
//when only 1 & 2 are open
$('#btnA').click(function () {
    closeall();
    //unique code
 }
//when 1, 3 & 4 are open
$('#btnB').click(function () {
    closeall();
    //unique code
 }
//when only 5 & 6 are open
$('#btnC').click(function () {
    closeall();
    //unique code
 }
 function closall() {
    modal1.style.display = "none"; 
    modal2.style.display = "none";
    modal3.style.display = "none"; 
    modal4.style.display = "none";
    modal5.style.display = "none"; 
    modal6.style.display = "none";
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would do the latter (One `closeAll` function). You won't lose a noticeable amount of performance by re-setting CSS attributes for any reasonable number of modals.

Possibly you may not lose much at all -  depending on how the browser implements a CSS change - IE: If it checks if the new value differs from the old value.

I *would* however modify it slightly to make it easier to deal with other modals in the future:

```
function closeAll() {
    var modals = [modal1, modal2, modal3, modal4, modal5, modal6];

    for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
        modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Which will greatly reduce your line count as the number of modals grows.

You could even make a check, however this will probably be more expensive than the one above:

```
function closeAll() {
    var modals = [modal1, modal2, modal3, modal4, modal5, modal6];

    for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
        if (getComputedStyle(modals[i]).getPropertyValue('display') != "none") {
            modals[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I look at this from the idea of what happens when you need to add some additional modals down the road...doing it like your second example makes it easier for you to just keep track in one place all that need to be closed...so the efficiency is in having to edit in less places I guess.

In thinking about controlling what gets turned on, you can consider using the data attribute and storing a JSON object that lists the modals you want on, then send to one function that grabs the data object, turns everything off but then turns on just the ones in the object, then you attach one function to all buttons with a specific class. This lets you abstract away all the rest...in the HTML, just decide then what is happening. Note: this is good if the switches are meant for modals only and not other actions based on the button itself.  If you need to add other actions you, you can send the id of the clicked button into another function and run a switch to decide what else gets done.  Taking this direction might be efficient if your project will have a lot of functionality as you describe, as it grows, your only need to worry about the 1 case in the 1 switch to add/edit with 1 attached handle and the JSON is right there in the HTML when you are creating the modals anyways.  Otherwise, for debugging and editing later, you'd have many separate attached handles to spin through and add/edit.

```
// HTML
<button id="b1" class="modbuts" data-modalson='{"on":["m1","m3"]}'>b1</button>
<button id="b2" class="modbuts" data-modalson='{"on":["m2","m4"]}'>b2</button>
<button id="b3" class="modbuts" data-modalson='{"on":["m1","m4"]}'>b3</button>
<button id="b4" class="modbuts" data-modalson='{"on":["m2","m3"]}'>b4</button>
<div id="otherDiv"></div>
<div id="m1" class="mods" style="display:none;">m1</div>
<div id="m2" class="mods" style="display:none;">m2</div>
<div id="m3" class="mods" style="display:none;">m3</div>

// attach handler in your script
$('.modbuts').click(function () {
        var modalson = $(this).data('modalson') ;
    $('.mods').hide();
    $.each(modalson.on,function(index,m){
        $('#'+m).show();
    });
    otherActions($(this).attr('id'));


 });

 function otherActions(id){
 switch(id) {
        case "b1":
    $('#otherDiv').html('Button #'+id+ ' was pressed, do js stuff here!');
    break;
            case "b2":
    $('#otherDiv').html('Button #'+id+ ' was pressed, do js stuff here!');
    break;
            case "b3":
    $('#otherDiv').html('Button #'+id+ ' was pressed, do js stuff here!');
    break;

    default:
    // dev/debug trail, ok to remove
    console.log('FYI, no actions attached to #'+id +' to run in otherActions.')
 }
 }
```

Here is a fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bn2wxqt/1/)